# Deleting Lightning Component referenced in Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, delete

I'm trying to clean up my sandbox org but when I attempt to delete a certain Lightning Component, I get the following error:

> This component is found in 0 Development Instance(s) and 1 Published Instance(s). Use the following component paths to locate the component:
>                 [Published] My Application > Application Detail (Widget) > content (Panel) > myApplicationPath (Aura)  : c:myApplicationPath.

I went in to the Community Builder in sandbox and deleted the component from the community, which brought the Development Instances down to 1, but I really don't understand what Published Instances could still hold this component?  I also removed it from the Production environment but that didn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you need to 'Publish' the community from the community builder after removing the component (even if it's still in Preview), once that's done you should be able to delete the component.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the

1. The pages mentioned
2. The variations of the builder pages.

If that still doesn't solves the problem then it is likely that you created the page, added the component and then changed the layout and added the component again.

If you have used just a single layout, then you should not see that error but I suspect that you used another layout before for the same page. If you have, switch to that layout and remove the components, then switch to original layout and publish.

Example.

You created one page and used 1 column layout for that, and added your component there. 
Then you realized that the layout doesn't works well and  you changed the layout to 2 columns without removing the component first.

Now the  1 column layout even though not visible still holds the reference to the component. To remove that change the layout from 2 column to one column. Remove the component and then switch back. 
Do this for all layouts that you have used before on the same page.

---

Enable the experience bundle metadata type and retrieve the community and run a search for the component and you will know where it is still being used.